# I propose banning the 'rank' tag

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, tag-management, tag-blacklist

I noticed that there were five recent questions tagged with [rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rank), out of a total of seven question.

These five questions where all about [rank in linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

Given the multitude of meanings of [*rank* in mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank#Mathematics), not all isomorphic, I decided to create the tag [matrix-rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-rank) and removed all instances of *rank*.

No matter how useful the tag *matrix rank* is, it certainly is more so than the ambiguous tag *rank*.

I propose to ban the tag *rank*, whether the tag *matrix rank* sticks or not.

How does one actually go about making such a proposal?

Comment: Try removing the tag first by retagging all the questions it currently is attached to. Blacklisting it typically only done for tags that are likely to be ressurected by the community. If the tag reappears, blacklisting might make sense.

Comment: @MadScientist I see. I already removed all the instances of the tag. Thanks.

Comment: With the fairly recently implemented [higher rep requirement to create tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12480/8348), once [tag:rank] is removed with any luck it won't come back.

Comment: BTW some references explaining that tag is deleted after being removed from questions (and also some additional details): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/deleting-tags-after-being-created

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution would be making [rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rank) a synonym of of [matrix-rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-rank). (Considering that very probably most users using (rank) tag would use it in this meaning.)

Please, downvote/upvote this post to show whether you think making the two tag synonymous would be good idea.

(This is independent from the question whether (matrix-rank) is worth keeping or not.)